# Оптимизация валидации xml

Tags: c#, xml

Обмениваюсь документами со сторонним сервисом. Все документы в формате XML. Если что-то идет не так, сервис сообщает об ошибке также с помощью XML специального формата (у меня есть его xsd-схема). Форматов документов очень много, но при каждом запросе я точно знаю какой формат будет иметь ответ (если не будет ошибки).

Я написал следующий метод для проверки успешности запроса:

```
void CheckErrorSchema(string text)
{
    var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema };
    using (var sr = new StringReader(Properties.Resources.ErrorSchema)) // xsd-схема сообщения об ошибке
    using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        settings.Schemas.Add(null, xr);
    using (var sr = new StringReader(text))
    using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr, settings))
    {
        try
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(xr);
            throw new MyException(...);
        }
        catch (XmlSchemaValidationException) { }
    }
}
```

Т.е. после получения ответа, я вызываю этот метод и если он выполнился нормально, то десериализую ответ в нужный мне формат.

Мне не нравится, что сейчас я загружаю документ и если его загрузка бросает исключение, то я его подавляю и считаю что всё нормально. А если документ загрузился без проблем, то я бросаю исключение. Ошибки бывают достаточно редко (порядка 1% случаев).

Как можно это оптимизировать?

Comment: Не понял, а зачем вы бросаете своё исключение? Может, стоить возвращать булево значение? True - успех, false - ошибка.

Comment: Потому что класс, в котором это происходит не способен обработать ситуацию и мне ее надо обработать уже в вызывающем коде. Т.е. это класс-обертка над сервисом, я создаю его экземпляр и говорю ему найди мне документ с таким номером, а он мне его возвращает или бросает исключение, если был получен xml-ошибка

Comment: Т.е. эта часть, которая бросает исключение, меня устраивает. А вот то что приходится намеренно идти на исключительную ситуацию и проглатывать ее, когда все нормально - именно это смущает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал код следующим образом:

```
void CheckErrorSchema(string text)
{
    var schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();
    using (var sr = new StringReader(Properties.Resources.ErrorSchema))
    using (var xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
        schemas.Add(null, xr);
    using (var sr = new StringReader(text))
    {
        var error = true;
        var doc = XDocument.Load(sr);
        doc.Validate(schemas, (s, e) => error = false);
        if (error) throw new MyException(...);
    }
}
```

Метод-расширения [`Extensions.Validate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb340331(v=vs.110).aspx) для `XDocument` при несоответствии xml схеме не бросает исключение, а вызывает колбэк. В качестве колбэка я использую простое лямбда-выражение, которое снимает флаг наличия ошибок.

Быстрее это работать не стало, но, по крайней мере, я избавился от кучи красных ромбиков в окне диагностики VS.